# In Java, can a final field be initialized from a constructor helper?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, final

I have a final non-static member:

```
private final HashMap<String,String> myMap;
```

I would like to initialize it using a method called by the constructor. Since myMap is final, my "helper" method is unable to initialize it directly. Of course I have options:

I could implement the myMap initialization code directly in the constructor.

```
MyConstructor (String someThingNecessary)
{
    myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    myMap.put("blah","blahblah");
    // etc...

    // other initialization stuff unrelated to myMap
}
```

I could have my helper method build the HashMap, return it to the constructor, and have the constructor then assign the object to myMap.

```
MyConstructor (String someThingNecessary)
{
    myMap = InitializeMyMap(someThingNecessary);

    // other initialization stuff unrelated to myMap
}

private HashMap<String,String> InitializeMyMap(String someThingNecessary)
{
    HashMap<String,String> initializedMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    initializedMap.put("blah","blahblah");
    // etc...

    return initializedMap;
}
```

Method #2 is fine, however, I'm wondering if there's some way I could allow the helper method to directly manipulate myMap. Perhaps a modifier that indicates it can only be called by the constructor?

```
MyConstructor (String someThingNecessary)
{
    InitializeMyMap(someThingNecessary);

    // other initialization stuff unrelated to myMap
}


// helper doesn't work since it can't modify a final member
private void InitializeMyMap(String someThingNecessary)
{
    myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    myMap.put("blah","blahblah");
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Do you know what people answering your question will do? Yes, they will try it out by opening Eclipse and copy-pasting your code! :)

Comment: @Simon My question is requesting an alternative to what I have tried. I am wondering if someone with better knowledge of that language than I can guide me to a keyword or paradigm I am unaware of.

Comment: the answer is No. Source: Java language specification 8.3.1.2

Comment: ;)... np... but that's what I did ^^

Comment: @Simon I guess I wasn't sure what you were getting at. I thought perhaps you were implying that I could have answered my own question by trying out my code in Eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Method #2 is your best option. The problem is that if you have an assignment in a private method there is nothing preventing other code in the class outside the constructor calling it, which would then create an issue with an attempted second assignment to the final field.

Java has no construct of a separate method that can only be called during construction.

For completeness, we can make a third option, where you assign the map at initialization and then have the helper method fill it:

```
 private final HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String();
```

And then:

```
 MyConstructor (String someThingNecessary)
 {
    initializeMyMap(someThingNecessary);

    // other initialization stuff unrelated to myMap
 }


 // helper doesn't work since it can't modify a final member
 private void initializeMyMap(String someThingNecessary)
 {

     myMap.clear();
    myMap.put("blah","blahblah");
    // etc...
  }
```

And if you really want to be confusing you can use an initializer instead of a constructor, but you should not do that, so unless you really need to know, I won't expand on that.

Comment: Actually, Java has. It's called a constructor ;-)

Comment: @Johannes no, he means there is no sub-constructor designation that would allow the assignment of final variables on the condition that the method could only be called from the constructor.

Comment: @Yishai. Thanks for the alternative. Also, regarding initializers, I don't think it would work anyway, since the HashMap contents are actually dependent on the argument given to the constructor.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but I can't think of a reason not to initialize it when it's declared as Yishai suggests here, then just fill it from the helper. Maybe csj could elaborate?

Comment: @Stephan P To my knowledge, a Java initializer cannot be provided any arguments upon object instantiation. This is in contrast to constructors which readily accept arguments, and can utilize them for initialization. Since the contents of my HashMap are dependent upon my constructor parameter, I cannot see any way to utilize an initializer - which Yishai mentioned in passing, in the last sentence of this answer.

Comment: @csj Yes, but the arguments to the initialization statement would be the *capacity* and *load factor* of the HashMap: `new HashMap<String,String>(30, 0.75)` **not** the contents of the map: `myMap.put("blah", "blahblah")` which can still be loaded within the helper method, because the map contents are not 'final', only the map itself.

Comment: @Stephen P. Okay, I get what you're saying now. Is there an advantage to creating the object in an initializer versus the constructor, if in either case its content initializing method will be called from the constructor?

Comment: @csj, well for this case it can help with the helper method. Otherwise it is just a matter of style. For example, you can be comfortable that no weird logic in the constructor left you with a null value (that doesn't apply to final, but in general).

Answer (score 14):

How about implementing a private constructor that initializes your HashMap, and then have your main constructor(s) call that private constructor?

For example--

```
// Helper function to initialize final HashMap.
private MyConstructor()
{
    myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("blah","blah");
}

MyConstructor (String someThingNecessary)
{
    // Initialize the HashMap.
    this();
    // Other initialization code can follow.
}
```

You can modify the signature of the private helper constructor as needed (e.g. to provide parameter data or to make the signature distinct from any public constructors).

Comment: I think this solution is what @Joey was alluding to above when he said, "Actually, Java has. It's called a constructor," in response to Yishai's remark that "Java has no construct of a separate method that can only be called during construction."

Comment: I kind of like this idea. Unfortunately, it prevents me from giving the method a sensible name (like, InitializeMyMap) that represents what it's initializing. Thank you for posting to an old question. I always appreciate new ideas, or clarification of old ones.

Comment: Thanks, @csj. I was looking for an answer to the same question and thought of this. None of the previously proposed approaches would work very well for my use case of simultaneously initializing several final fields. As for the name, yes, it could be better. But at least it's consistent with constructors initializing something. :) I'm new to Java and wouldn't be surprised if there's an even better solution out there.

Comment: This is a great answer. I have multiple constructors that all do very similar registration and data initialization. Each constructor is now a one-line call to a private constructor. All the differences come as parameters to the private constructor. This is much more maintainable!

Comment: This doesn't work because you can't have any other code before the call to this();

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 is the most resuable option, because you can share it among all constructors. What we would need here, are collection initializers of c#. :)

(BTW: #3 won't compile)

Comment: Thanks for your help Simon. I knew from the get-go that #3 wouldn't compile. I was hoping there might be a way to make it legal by guaranteeing that the helper would only be callable from the constructor. It appears that this isn't possible.